# translation in GLSL shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to move figure inside vertex GLSL shader:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 Position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 offset;

uniform mat4 ProjectionViewMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec3 newPos = Position;
    newPos.x += offset[0];
    newPos.y += offset[1];
    //newPos.z += offset[2];

    mat4 translation;
    translation[0][0] = 1;
    translation[1][1] = 1;
    translation[2][2] = 1;
    translation[2][3] = offset[2];
    translation[3][3] = 1;

    gl_Position = ProjectionViewMatrix * (translation * vec4(newPos, 1.0));
}
```

I would like to draw many similar objects, with different coordinates, so I'm using glDrawArraysInstanced and layout(location = 1) in vec3 offset; - dynamic buffer;

With translation matrix it does not work. But if I will uncomment line newPos.z += offset[2]; and remove translation matrix it would work.

I prefer to use matrix because in future I would like pass in shader info about scaling dynamically.
Why it does not work with matrix?

Comment: OpenGL matrices are stored in column-major order. Try setting element `[3][2]` instead of `[2][3]`.

Answer (score 4):

GLSL operates with matrices stored in column major order. Writing just the indices corresponding to a matrix the way you would normally write it:

```
[0][0]  [1][0]  [2][0]  [3][0]
[0][1]  [1][1]  [2][1]  [3][1]
[0][2]  [1][2]  [2][2]  [3][2]
[0][3]  [1][3]  [2][3]  [3][3]
```

To apply a translation while multiplying this matrix with a column vector on the right side, the translation vector goes into the first 3 elements of the last column, which are the index pairs `[3][0]`, `[3][1]`, and `[3][2]`. This means that the z-offset goes into matrix element `[3][2]`.

Answer (score 0):

To be extra clear, it seems you can build a translation matrix like so:

```
mat4 BuildTranslation(vec3 delta)
{
    mat4 m;
    m[0][0] = 1;
    m[1][1] = 1;
    m[2][2] = 1;
    m[3] = vec4(delta, 1.0);
    return m;
}
```

Or [this answer has another method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46776629/79125):

```
mat4 BuildTranslation(vec3 delta)
{
    return mat4(
        vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
        vec4(delta, 1.0));
}
```